# How to add a returned NSArray to a NSArray

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, xcode4

I am new to Objective-C and iPhone

I have to sort a NSDictionary using values and according to that i have to arrange the keys of that values, i have sorted the array.

```
//getting values
NSArray* keys1 = [sortDictionary allValues];    
NSArray* sortedArray = [keys1 sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b) {  
     return [a compare:b options:NSNumericSearch];
}];
```

My problem now is I am getting the keys of the values by allKeysForObject: , which returns an NSArray.

```
for( NSString* aStr in sortedArray ) {
    NSLog( @"%@ has value %@", [sortDictionary allKeysForObject:aStr], aStr );  
 }
```

> ```
> O/P :- (
>   Sourish
> ) has value 60
> ```

Rather i want "Sourish" as a string and store  it to a NSArray and than store that NSArray to NSDictionary or store both  Sourish and 60 to another NSDictionary

Kindly make me to sort our this problem.

Comment: I'm not finding the question easy to follow. If I'm understanding it right, it might help to change allKeysForObject: aStr to valueForKey: aStr. That will return an NSString if that's what you are using as your key. It's not clear whether sometimes you expect to have several copies of the same object in the dictionary and, if you do, what you want to do about that.

Comment: @Matthew Elton : yeah i tried with that , When i am trying with that i am getting a null value.

Comment: Oops. So it does. I think you might want something that does 'anyKeyForObject:' and returns just one key. See answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gets the string for you by looking at the array. Is that what you are after?

```
NSDictionary* sortDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"60", @"Sourish", @"45" , @"Peckish",  @"25", @"Swordfish", @"15", @"Mashmish", nil];

 NSArray* keys1 = [sortDictionary allValues];    
 NSArray* sortedArray = [keys1 sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b)
 {  
    return [a compare:b options:NSNumericSearch];
 }]; 

 for( NSString* aStr in sortedArray )
 {
    NSString* keyForObject = @"";

    if ([[sortDictionary allKeysForObject: aStr] count] > 0)
    {
        keyForObject = [[sortDictionary allKeysForObject: aStr] objectAtIndex: 0];
    }

     NSLog( @"%@ has value %@", keyForObject, aStr );  
 }
```

This logs:

```
Mashmish has value 15
Swordfish has value 25
Peckish has value 45
Sourish has value 60
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `NSMutableArray` to store your data using `addObject: selector`
or use `NSMutableDictionary` to store both as key:value pare using `addObjectsAndKeys: selector`

Answer (score 0):

> ">> I have to sort a NSDictionary using values and according to that i have to arrange the keys of that values"

```
NSArray *allkey =[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[sortDictionary keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]] ;
```

Implement your compare method,

```
 - (NSComparisonResult)compare:(id)b {
    return [self compare:b options:NSNumericSearch];
}
```

The allkey is the keys array sorted using values.